# How do I file a certificate of service when making a money claim online?

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-procedure, small-claims-court, court

I recently submitted online a court claim for money owed.

Prior to making the claim I had written to the defendant several times to explain the breakdown of money owed but not got a response.

Now that it's been more than 14 days since the claim was submitted and he has not responded, I can proceed to a request for judgment.

The page says: "*If you served separate detailed particulars of claim on the defendant(s), you must have filed a certificate of service within 14 days of serving these and, where you've done this, you must confirm this if you proceed to request judgment.*"

I sent the separate detailed particulars on several occasions before the money claim.  And I have resent them now.  However, I don't know what a 'certificate of service' is, or how I can 'file' such a thing.

Comment: A certificate of service is a statement signed by you or whoever sent it, stating that an exact copy of the claim you filed with the court (not any other communications with the other party) was sent to the person being sued and stating the means by which this was done. A claim filed in court is only valid if it has been properly delivered to the person being sued. This certificate of service must be delivered to the clerk of the court. I don't know how efiling in small claims court in the UK handles this issue. The instructions for filing a small claims lawsuit should clarify this point.

Comment: Details here: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/609046/MCOL_Userguide_for_Claimants_April_2017.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I finally got from the County Court Business Centre was:

> To file a Certificate of Service please complete the attached N215.
>
> Then send the N215 to:   E-mail:           ccbc@hmcts.gsi.gov.uk
>
> Fax:                0870 324 0166 / 0870 324 0036
>   Post:
>   The County Court Business Centre 
>   St Katharine's House 21-27 St
>   Katharine Street 
>   Northampton NN1 2LH

The N215 form can be downloaded [here](https://formfinder.hmctsformfinder.justice.gov.uk/n215-eng.pdf)